# Azure Website - Web.config transform fails "No element in the source document matches /configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration"

Tags: asp.net, azure, web.config-transform

Our ASP.NET Web Api project has two deployment configurations (.pubxml):

1. Web deployment directly to Azure Websites.
2. Package deployment to a local Zip file.

The Web deployment (1) works just fine. 
The Package deployment to a zip is failing with the following errors:

```
Warning 3   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.identityModel'     20  10  MyWebProject
Error   4   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration'       21  10  MyWebProject
```

Looking at the verbose logs, I can see it's **failing during the Web.config transform.**

```
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ida:AudienceUri']'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing SetTokenizedAttributes (transform line 7, 9)
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ida:Realm']'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing SetTokenizedAttributes (transform line 10, 9)
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='ida:FederationMetadataLocation']'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing SetTokenizedAttributes (transform line 13, 9)
 Warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.identityModel'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing RemoveAll (transform line 24, 14)
 Error : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.identityModel/identityConfiguration'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing Insert (transform line 27, 9)
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.identityModel'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing SetTokenizedAttributes (transform line 33, 9)
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.identityModel.services'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing SetTokenizedAttributes (transform line 42, 9)
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.identityModel.services'
        ParameterizeTransformXml:   Not executing SetTokenizedAttributes (transform line 45, 9)
        ParameterizeTransformXml: Transformation failed
        Done executing task "ParameterizeTransformXml" -- FAILED.
        Done building target "_TransformWebConfigForAzureAuthenticationCore" in project "MyWebProject.csproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "MyWebProject.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

**What additional build information do I need to configure to get the Zip deployment past these errors?** It works just fine if I do a direct web deployment.

Answer (score 27):

Check your publish settings to see if you have EnableADPublish set to true.  That was my problem (I was configuring Azure AD Auth through other means), so I just set it to false and everything worked great.

```
<EnableADPublish>false</EnableADPublish>
```

Cheers,
Jeff

Comment: This worked for me as well, but do we have any idea why?

Comment: Same. No idea what EnableADPublish is, but worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the publish wizard, make sure that "Enable Organizational Authentication" is unchecked**. This fixed it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I added the below configuration explicitly:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>        
      </audienceUris>
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

It is able to create the package finally!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the system.identityModel elements in your configuration for AD integration. If you want to integrate with the azure AD, you need to [enable Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568638(v=vs.110).aspx) in your configuration.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!--WIF 4.5 sections -->
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </configSections>

  ...

  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost/WebApplication1/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="313D3B … 9106A9EC" name="SelfSTS" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>

  ...

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but I just had this problem and the only thing that solved it for me was to re-download the publish profile from the Azure Web App Overview blade's "Get Publish Profile" button.  Then I had to import it into the solution.

Hope that helps someone!